# Knowing if time has passed in java

Tags: java, date, time

I would like to know if the `current time has passed 12 pm` already. Can I do it in an if statement like:

```
if(timenow is already pass 12 pm){

**do code here**

}
```

Is there a java code or a method in joda time that can do that? All answers are appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Isn't the current time always past some 12pm?

Comment: Yes, java has Date class that can do this

Answer (score 3):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 12) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: For Java 8: `LocalTime.now().getHour() >= 12`. Also "has passed" could be interpreted as `LocalTime.now().isAfter(LocalTime.NOON)` where the exact time of `12:00:00.000000000` is not included.

Comment: What if I have a given date like 2015-11-04 00:42:20. How do I get the hour for that?

Comment: Use a SimpleDateFormat object to convert that to a Date then setTime() on the Calendar with that Date.

Answer (score 1):

**JAVA**

```
int hour = LocalDateTime.now().getHour();
```

**JODATIME**

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();  // current time
int hour = dt.getHourOfDay(); // gets hour of day
```

and put the logic here

```
if(hour >= 12){
   do code here
}
```

Comment: Isn't `hour <= 24` rather meaningless?

Comment: `LocalTime` would be better than `LocalDateTime`. Less overhead, since a `LocalDateTime` is basically the combination of `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`.

Comment: This code implicitly uses the JVM’s current default time zone. You may want to specify a time zone object explicitly.